# Quick way to link Objects from screen to View Model

Tags: c#, xaml

Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this quicker without defining two string or objects?

Xaml

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Width="100" Text={Binding Path=dataString}></TextBox>
```

View Model

```
string _dataString;
public string dataString
{
    get
    {
        return _dataString;
    }
    set
    {
        _dataString = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really.. What would you bind to without the property? Are you just looking to save key-strokes when designing your view models?

Comment: Create a code snippet? Saves hours a week!

Comment: You have the simplest possible binding. This "overhead" may seem like a pain, but the good design will save you a ton of time and effort in the future, and the stuff you can do because of the way bindings work is incredible.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes - this seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me, and most of the comments seem like they should be answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define helpers to shorten the syntax somewhat. For example, if you use the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), and inherit your ViewModel from `ViewModelBase`, the toolkit provides a helper that enables use of the following syntax:

```
private string _dataString = null;

public string DataString
{
    get { return _dataString; }
    set { Set(ref _dataString, value); }
}
```

You still have to provide a backing field, but the helper takes care of notifying the *exact* property that changed, and only raises the event if the new value is in fact different from the current one.

You can also speed up the process of adding the properties by [creating a custom code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165396.aspx) and importing it into Visual Studio via the Code Snippets Manager.